# How to avoid getting confused with all the ion-things in ion

Tags: ionic-framework, intel-xdk

In ionic framework there is a lot of tags such as:

- `ion-view`
- `ion-content`
- `ion-nav-bar`
- `div class="..."`

**What to use? How to keep my app structure clean? Any skeleton generator?**
I am using intel xdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to ionic framework starter project for [**Intel XDK**](http://xdk.intel.com):

https://github.com/krisrak/ionic-angularjs-intelxdk-seed

there is also a ionic framework kitchen-sink app that you can refer to:

https://github.com/krisrak/ionic-angularjs-kitchensink

Comment: Hi Krisrak, as I know the latest current release of XDK change a bit of their template for Blank App project. Do your Ionic XDK seed updated to that template? Please advice, thank you.